# How to edit my function to return an error if password isn't 8 characters?

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript but it works fine with all the other fields when nothing is entered I'm trying to make the user need to enter at least 8 characters before submitting but currently, they can submit on 0.

```
function validateForm() {
    if (document.register.firstName.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your first name!");
        document.register.firstName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.register.secondName.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your second name!");
        document.register.secondName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.register.email.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your Email!");
        document.register.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.register.phoneNo.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your Phone Number!");
        document.register.phoneNo.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.register.Gender.value == "") {
        alert("Must select a Gender!");
        document.register.Gender.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.register.Terms.value == "") {
        alert("Terms and Conditions must be accpeted");
        document.register.Terms.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.register.psw.value.length > 7) {
        alert("Password must contain 8 character");
        document.register.psw.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return (true);
}
```

Comment: `document.register.psw.value.length > 7` shouldn't it be `document.register.psw.value.length < 8` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if it's `<= 7` characters in length (or probably `< 8` for clarity). Currently you're preventing the user from submitting a password if it's too *long*, not the other way around:

```
if (document.register.psw.value.length < 8) { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the password input field. If so, you can handle that from the HTML by doing something like this (see below) and have the browser handle the validation.

```
<input type="password" minlength="4" maxlength="8">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following. Notice, as you mentioned, it is not greater than 7, but less than 8.

```
if( document.register.psw.value.length < 8) {
    alert( "Password must contain 8 character" );
    document.register.psw.focus() ;
    return false;
}
```